# Multiple COUNT() conditions for values on either side of a range

Tags: mysql

I currently have a query that finds all rows (with `status=0`) that have occurred before now:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(1) FROM tbl WHERE status = 0 AND date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() GROUP BY id;
```

However, now I'd *also* like to be able to retrieve the values on the other side of this--i.e., I want to get all dates available after **and** before now, as two distinct values.

Is there any way to optimize this besides simply running two separate queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id
     , SUM(date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) AS BeforeNow
     , SUM(date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) AS AfterNow
  FROM tbl
 WHERE status = 0
 GROUP BY id;
```

`date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is a boolean expression, which equates to 1 or 0. The `SUM` of the expression is equal to the amount of times it was true, or its count.

Comment: Can you please add some context around your answer. It will help the asker and readers both.

Comment: @RBT Honestly, I'm not sure which part needs more context, but I've added some explanation on the use of `SUM`, as it's somewhat less common.

Comment: Thank you and appreciate your prompt response. I just saw it in review queue and considered it a code-only answer. Hence I provided my feedback.

Comment: This is very clever, @shmosel!  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a conditional count.

```
SELECT id,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() THEN 1 ELSE null END ) ,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() THEN 1 ELSE null END ) 

FROM tbl GROUP BY id
```